# How to create a new table using Doctrine Query Language (DQL)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a importing system by using `Symfony2`. 
A new table must be automatically created when a user imports a new dataset.

For example, if the user imports 3 datasets, we will have `DataA`, `DataB`, and `DataC` tables.

I have been searching on "How to create and insert data in DQL", However, it's written that `DQL` doesn't have `Create` and `Insert` queries - Only `Select`, `Update`, and `Delete` are allowed.

So, what is the good practice to achieve this approach? I have only an idea in my head which is to create a `plain SQL query`, I don't know if this is a good way in `Symfony2` and `Doctrine`.

I think that it should be better if we could achieve this by using Object Relation Mapping, `ORM`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next code in controller:

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$sql = "CREATE TABLE __tablename__";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```